# Url signing in from PHP to Python

Tags: php, python, signing

I'm very new to Python and I'm working with an API which recently started required url signing. I have been advised that in PHP this code which will sign the url look like this:

```
function signUrl($url, $post = null)
{
if ($post !== null) { ksort($post); }
return md5(YourSecretApiKey . $url . ($post === null ? '' : implode(',', $post)));
}
```

How do I do this in Python?

That's my Python code:

```
import wykop

appkey = 'KEY'
secretkey = 'KEYa'

api = wykop.WykopAPI(appkey)
profile = api.get_profile("m__b")
print api.get_profile("m__b")
```

And I get an error:

```
wykop.InvalidAPISignError
```

Comment: Can you pester the authors of the API to give you a clearer specification? That's a godawful way of specifying how to make a hash signature, it's ambiguous w/r/t encoding for one. (That said, PHP *does* have documentation for all the functions used, it seems like you haven't even gone to read them and at least try to reimplement the algorithm.)

Comment: The PHP code I posted is actually what the API authors send me...I'll keep looking

Comment: Yes, and what they sent you is semi-abstruse, but SO is not a code porting service. You'll have to include the signing mechanism in however the `wykop` module is implemented. If it's not your module, pester the maintainers of it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Python version of that part of PHP code

```
import hashlib
# Ready for md5

def signUrl(url, post=None):

  # Set default. Empty for not provided
  post_string = ''

  if post is not None:

    # Dictionary in Python does not maintain order 
    # Sort it manually with a for loop instead
    post = [post[k] for k in sorted(post.keys())]

    post_string = ','.join(post)
    # PHP implode

  return hashlib.md5(YourSecretApiKey + url + post_string).hexdigest()
```